# Not able to partition table on Hive- Error in metadata

Tags: hadoop, hive, partition

I have created a table in Hive with data loaded into it.

I want to partition it on Column spec: DoJ where value is 2012

I used:

```
ALTER TABLE employee
ADD PARTITION (year='2012')
location '/home/rvarun/2012/part2012';
```

I am getting the error:

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: table is not partitioned but partition spec exists: {year=2012}
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

I am a little new to Hive so please excuse me for any noobity.

The table I have looks like this:

```
1001    Varun   100000  Security Lead   2011
1002    Saloni  85000   Database Admin  2012
1003    Karan   90000   Network Engineer Lead   2012
1004    Pratik  98000   TrainEngine Driver  2012
1005    Ashish  120000  Senior Consultant   2013
1006    Gautam  70000   Salesforce Consultant   2013
1007    Mohit Sacheva   20000   Peon    2014
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? TIA

Comment: Please provide your create table script and output of **show partitions employee**

Comment: did my solution work?

Answer (score 1):

Your table is not created properly. Let's say your table name is my_table. you should include

```
'PARTITIONED BY (year string)'
```

so your create table should look like below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table 
(col1 string,
col2 string,
col3 string)
PARTITIONED BY (year string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/home/rvarun/2012/part2012';
```

If you want to use column name as DoJ, just replace year with DoJ in partitioned by.